# In R Studio, how to save your graphs?

Tags: r, graph, plot, rstudio

I now use Projects in R Studio to conduct all my R programming activities.  Based on the writings of Josh Paulson at the R Studio website, I expected that when you close Project, it would save all your settings including your Plots.  But, invariably it does not.  How can you best save plots within your R environment?  I am not talking of saving them as separate PDF files, etc... that I am comfortable with.

Comment: I don't know for certain if RStudio would handle it differently, but have you checked out `?windows` (specifically `windows(record=TRUE)`) and `?replayPlot`? With my 5 seconds of research, it appears that perhaps `.SavedPlots` will only store 4 plots, so this may not be a full-time solution. You might have to home-bake a solution using `.SavedPlots` and a self-maintained list of `recordedplot`.

Comment: r2evans, those are good leads.  Thanks

Comment: IMHO saving workspace, variables, plots, etc, is a *horrible* "feature." Instead, save your scripts (scripts that create those plots), start with a clean session every time you open r. Edit your .rprofile if you *must* have (or just what to have) certain settings every time, use `saveRDS`, `save`, `save.image`, etc *explicitly* if you must or if you have created a time-consuming object via a simulation or whatever and load those objects explicitly.

Comment: rawr, so you suggest that save.image is better than going through the Project interface?